# Disabling buttons when a certain variable is zero? [solved: Observer Design Pattern]

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, observer-pattern

i am creating a simple combat game. there are two opposing players whose objective is to eliminate the other; i have created health bars, and the like. to launch an attack against an opponent, the user clicks a certain button "attack". i want this button to be disabled if one player's healthbar has reached zero.

[frame http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/Untitled.jpg](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/Untitled.jpg)

The structure of my program:

main class (public class App extends JFrame)
 //private JButtons, JPanels, etc.

public App()
   //layout of all components and registered listeners

main method
  //frame/s (i have more than one frame in my main method. haha)

Listener class/es
 //if else statements (if (e.getSource == xyz))

JPanel class/es that draws health bars

----end of structure

here's what i've done so far on the panel class(the total source code is an 800-line txt file):

```
    class HP2panel extends JPanel {

    public void damageTake() {
    if (widthHP <= 0) {   
    damageToMe = 0;
    }
    else if (widthRage >= 250) {  
    damageToMe = 175 + (int)(Math.random() * 25);
    }
    else if (widthHP > 0 && widthRage < 250) { 
    damageToMe = Math.round(1 + (int)(Math.random() * 15));
    }
    if (widthHP2 <= 0) {
    damageToMe = 0;
    }
    widthHP2 = widthHP2 - damageToMe;

    logtxt.append("\nYour HP: " + widthHP2);
    logtxt.append("\nDamage you've taken: " + damageToMe);
    repaint();
}

public void healdamageTake() {
    if (widthHP2 <= 0) {
    Heal = 0;
    }
    if (widthHP2 >= 250) {
    Heal = 0;
    }
    else {
    Heal = (int)(Math.random() * 25);
    }
    widthHP2 = widthHP2 + Heal;
    logtxt.append("\n");
    logtxt.append("\nHealed HP: " + Heal);
    repaint();
}

public void restartHP2() {
    widthHP2 = 250;
    repaint();
}

    @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, widthHP2, 16);
}


    }
```

HP2panel is the panel class in which the healthbar(fillRect) of player 2 is drawn. widthHP, widthRage are params from other panel class i've made.

i want the attack button disabled once widthHP goes zero or less than.
i've worked on if statements but it seemed useless.

i don't know whether i'm gonna put it on my Listener class or wherever else in my code.

Comment: Random aside, you probably want to read about [compound assignment operators](http://java.about.com/b/2009/05/23/java-term-of-the-week-compound-assignment-operator.htm), most programmers flinch at seeing `x = x - y` and don't bother reading further...

Comment: ya, i'll do that later. thanks. for now i really need to figure out the solution to my problem with the help of someone from here. i am at my wit's end.

Comment: your requirement is not completely clear to me. `button.setEnable(false)` could easily do the trick with an `if-else` check.

Comment: were should  put this if statement? i've edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that key is to use an **[Observer Design Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html)** to allow one object to listen for changes in state in another object.

I assume that each Player class has a health field. I would make this a "bound" property by giving the Player class a private SwingPropertyChangeSupport field, by giving the Player class `addPropertyChangeListener` and `removePropertyChangeListener` methods, and by notifying your listeners of health changes by calling `firePropertyChange(...)` method whenever the health property is changed inside of its `setHealth(...)` method. This way any class that needs to listen for changes to health (or any other bound property of the Player class) can do so and can respond to these changes as need be. This is another reason why class fields/properties should be private and only changed via setter methods.

For example:

### Driver class, PropChangeEg.java

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class PropChangeEg {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prop Change Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new PlayerPanel(new Player("Pete")));
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

### Player.java class

```
class Player {
   public static final String HEALTH = "health";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChangeSupport = 
             new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private String name;
   private int health = 100;

   public Player(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public int getHealth() {
      return health;
   }

   public void setHealth(int health) {
      int oldValue = this.health;
      int newValue = health;
      this.health = health;
      propChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(HEALTH, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

### PlayerPanel.java class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {
   private Player player;
   private JButton fireButton = new JButton("Fire");
   private JSlider healthSlider;

   public PlayerPanel(final Player player) {
      this.player = player;
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Player: " + 
             player.getName()));

      healthSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, player.getHealth());
      healthSlider.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Health"));
      healthSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      healthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      healthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      healthSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      healthSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);

      add(healthSlider);
      add(fireButton);

      healthSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            player.setHealth(healthSlider.getValue());
         }
      });

      player.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(Player.HEALTH)) {
               fireButton.setEnabled(player.getHealth() > 0);
            }
         }
      });

   }

   public Player getPlayer() {
      return player;
   }

}
```

This will result in a JButton that responds to the value held by the Player's health. For example, here are two screens from this GUI, one with a positive non-zero health value, and one where the health value of Player is zero:

[image]